# Matplotlib plot in PyQt5 UI doesn't update when the plot is changed

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm working on Python/Qt5 project where I use matplotlib for rendering some plots, the problem I have is that after updating this widget with a new plot the figure doesn't update until I resize the window, the problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56734864/plot-doesnt-update-on-button-click-but-does-when-window-resized) but the solution didn't work for me. I created a custom widget to contain matplotlib figure, added an empty widget in Qt Designer and promoted it to this custom widget:

```
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtCore, QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class PlotWidget(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        plt.style.use('dark_background')
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.figure)
        self.setParent(parent)
```

For plotting I use some classes from another module, for example this is a function that makes one of the plots:

```
def plot_fft_spectrogram(self, widget, symmetric=False):
    fft_x, fft_y = self.fft(symmetric=symmetric)

    widget.figure, axis = plt.subplots(1,1)
    axis.plot(fft_x, fft_y)
    axis.grid(ls=':')
    axis.set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    axis.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
    widget.figure.tight_layout()
    #This is the solution from the thread
    widget.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
```

This function is called from my `mainwindow.py` that when calling this plotting function it passes `self.ui.plot_widget` (which is the custom widget with matplotlib figure) as `widget argument`:

```
self.fourier_analyzer.plot_fft_spectrogram(self.ui.plot_widget, symmetric=symmetric)
```

I tried the answer described in the thread mentioned above but it didn't work. The figure doesn't update until I resize my window. My question is how to update either Qt widget or matplotlib figure contained in it automatically?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It it hard to help without a reproducible example, but my suggestion is not to inherit from FigureCanvas as it seems to be creating some confusion.

For setting the plot style you can use,

```
with plt.style.context("dark_background"):
    # your plot goes here
```

That being said, in your code when you create the subplots, you are overwriting  `widget.figure` and by doing it you lose the reference to the figure that was initiated in `FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.figure)`.

You can try with add subplot instead,

```
axis = widget.figure.add_subplot(111)
```

Comment: using `axis = widget.figure.add_subplot(111)` actually solved the problem, thank you!